# rebar compile fails with bitcask - "errno.h": no such file

Tags: compilation, makefile, erlang, rebar

I am new to Erlang, so i am going through Joe Armstrong's book "Programming Erlang". In chapter 25 there's an example on how to work with rebar. I followed the instructions and created a Makefile

```
all:
    test -d deps || rebar get-deps
    rebar compile -v
    @erl -noshell -pa './deps/bitcask/ebin' -pa './ebin' -s myapp start
```

and rebar.config

```
{deps, [
    {bitcask, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/basho/bitcask.git", "master"}}
]}.
```

Getting the dependencies works, but compiling fails.

The verbose output tells me that this command fails

```
cmd: cc -c $CFLAGS -g -Wall -fPIC  -I"/usr/lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.7.18/include" -I"/usr/lib/erlang/erts-6.2/include"   c_src/bitcask_nifs.c -o c_src/bitcask_nifs.o
```

with this error

```
/home/user/folder/deps/bitcask/c_src/bitcask_nifs.c:22:19: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory
```

But

```
find /usr/include -name errno.h
```

gives me

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/errno.h
/usr/include/asm/errno.h
/usr/include/linux/errno.h
/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h
```

So I was asking myself..

- what am I missing?
- how can I tell rebar about the depencies on the C libraries and where to find them?
- why isn't this configured correctly in the Makefile of bitcask?

Maybe I was searching for the wrong terms, but I couldn't find any solution in the internets.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two thing to consider

### rebar options

You can set options for compiling C code with [`port_env` option in `rebar.config`](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/blob/master/rebar.config.sample#L62).

### comiling deps

Since bitstack is your dependency, it is not compiled with yours rebar config, but with it's own.  So if you would like to change anything, you would have to modify the bitcask file.

Fortunately, if you look into [config their writen](https://github.com/basho/bitcask/blob/develop/rebar.config#L12) all C compilation is done with environment variable `$ERL_CFLAGS`.  And again, in [rebar source code](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/blob/master/src/rebar_port_compiler.erl#L58) you can see that this flag is responsible for include paths in your compilation.

So easist way would be extending `$ERL_CFLAGS` in your Makefile before compilation, with something like this

```
all: ERL_CFLAGS = "$ERL_CFLAGS -I /usr/include/linux/errno.h"
all: 
    test -d deps || rebar get-deps
    rebar compile -v
    @erl -noshell -pa './deps/bitcask/ebin' -pa './ebin' -s myapp start
```

Just make sure that this include works for you, and that you are not overwriting any flags you are using.